# How to dynamically load microapplications with single-spa

Tags: reactjs, single-spa, single-spa-react

I'm trying to build a React root application that loads micro applications dynamically based on logged user role.

My root application has been created with create-react-app.

index.tsx is like this

```
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { registerApplication, start } from 'single-spa';
registerApplication(
    'root',
    () => import('./root.app.js'),
    () => true,
);
start();
reportWebVitals();
```

I'm using `oidc-react` to manage authentication and I'm using it in this way:

```
import { AuthProvider } from 'oidc-react';
const oidcConfig = {....}
function App() {
  return (
      <AuthProvider {...oidcConfig} >
          <Layout />
      </AuthProvider>
  );
}
```

Layout component is like:

```
const Layout = () => {
   useEffect(()=>{
        registerDynamicApplication("http://localhost:8500/mf-video.js", "mf-container");
    }, []);

   return (
      <>
         <div id="mf-container">

         </div>
      </>
   )
};
```

Where `registerDynamicApplication` is:

```
export const registerDynamicApplication = (url, id, customProps = {}) => {
    let parcel = null;
    if (document.getElementById(id)) {
        parcel = mountRootParcel(() => import(url), {
            domElement: document.getElementById(id),
            ...customProps
        });
    }
    return parcel;
}
```

In the `useEffect` will be present the api call to fetch applications based on user role.

When I try to load microapplication in this way I receive error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module 'http://localhost:8500/mf-video.js'
    at utils|lazy|groupOptions: {}|namespace object:5:1
```

The microapplication has been created with the cli command:

```
create-single-spa --moduleType app-parcel --framework react
```

without touching anything.

When I try to access http://localhost:8500/mf-video.js, I reach to get content:

[image]

Do you have idea why first load of mf is not working?

Thank you!

Comment: The root-config should not have any frameworks, see also the docs here: https://single-spa.js.org/docs/faq/#should-i-have-a-parentroot-app-and-children-apps attempting to do it this way makes it less likely that you'll find a solution. I would strongly recommend not pursuing this approach.